# returning the value of an if statement within a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, function, if-statement, random

I'm trying to write a function that returns a random number for every new student registered, but each time the form is submitted the function returns a null value, and the DB does not accept null values, it ought to return something like this: DFA/SSS/22/1246 here's the code:

```
function createRegNumber()
{
    $schname = "DFA";
    $month = date("m");
    $year = date("Y");
    $new_year = substr($year, 2, 2);

    $base_year = 2019; // Set a base when the intakes started

    $intake = intval($year) - $base_year; // This will increase for every year

    $increase_with = $intake++;


    if ($month == '3') {
        $intake += $increase_with;
        $reg_no = $schname . "/" . $_POST['category'] . "/" . $new_year . "/" . rand(1000, 9999);
    } else if ($month == '9') {
        $increase_with++;
        $intake += $increase_with;
        $reg_no = $schname . "/" . $_POST['category'] . "/" . $new_year . "/" . rand(1000, 9999);

    }
    return $reg_no;
}
```

Comment: $intake appears to be unused before returning. @dave's answer already fixes the behaviour of the script for each month of year, but is it normal that you make increments on variables without using them after ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is that you return `$reg_no` but unless `$month == '3'` or `$month == '9'` it never gets set.  Most likely you want:

```
if ($month == '3') {
    $intake += $increase_with;
} else if ($month == '9') {
    $increase_with++;
    $intake += $increase_with;
}
$reg_no = $schname . "/" . $_POST['category'] . "/" . $new_year . "/" . rand(1000, 9999);
return $reg_no;
```